# Rounding off automatically in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two seperate dataframes ticket_id and id on one and ticket_id and value on other when I left join these two dataframes in python on ticket_id my id column is rounding off itself and I'm getting something like this

[image]

but what it actually is

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's easier for people to answer if you can provide your code *as* code, rather than as images.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
df_1.assign(ticket_id=df_1.ticket_id.astype(str)).merge(
    df_2.assign(ticket_id=df_2.ticket_id.astype(str)),
    how="left", on="ticket_id"
)
```